# Why using integer type for partition key can minimize memory usage?

Tags: hdfs, impala, cloudera-cdh

> Use smallest appropriate integer types for partition key columns.Although it is tempting to use strings for partition key columns,
> since those values are turned into HDFS directory names anyway, you
> can minimize memory usage by using numeric values for common partition
> key fields such as YEAR, MONTH, and DAY. Use the smallest integer type
> that holds the appropriate range of values, typically TINYINT for
> MONTH and DAY, and SMALLINT for YEAR. Use the EXTRACT() function to
> pull out individual date and time fields from a TIMESTAMP value, and
> CAST() the return value to the appropriate integer type.

The above paragraph comes from Cloudera. Why using integer type for partition key can minimize memory usage? Just because of the HDFS file name?

Comment: This is partition section of cloudera - The data type of the partition columns does not have a significant effect on the storage required, because the values from those columns are not stored in the data files, rather they are represented as strings inside HDFS directory names. Link https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_partitioning.html

Comment: I can see your source but i think there should be no difference between string or int key. You can see this stackoverlfow link as well. My personal experience there is no difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082114/hive-impala-performance-with-string-partition-key-vs-integer-partition-key

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter whether a partition key is int, string - storage wise its same. But it will work better in in-memory processing of SQL. Int always performs better in compared to string. so SQL will perform better in case you have many partitions, use partition key as int.

Comment: ok，Thank you very much。I misunderstand the meaning of  "memory usage"，It should refer to the memory used to execute SQL。